# Split multiple fields to rows in pentaho 'split field to rows' activity

Tags: pentaho

I have an array of phone numbers in my pentaho workflow. I am using split fields to rows activity and I am able to split that array to rows. Now I want to split multiple fields to row by using 'split field to rows' only once. I tried giving comma as a delimiter in the 'Fields to Split' in the input but getting error.
How I can split multiple fields to rows by using 'split fields to rows' activity once ?
[P.S. see attached image for referance]

Comment: The attached image is not attached.

Comment: What is the reason for using a single `Split field to row` ? Such a special architecture must have a reason !

Comment: You can chain as many `Split field to rows`as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Split field to rows` accept only one input field to split.

You may put a series of `Split field to rows`, one for each field.

Alternatively, you may concatenate your multiple fields in a single field before to split it.

Comment: Thanks AlainD. Is there any other way to split multiple fields instead of using a series of 'split fields to rows' activity ?

Comment: Since I don't know how many fields are getting added after every iteration; do you have any solution on the same ?

Comment: I do not understand the problem. The split field to rows will split the field containing "val1, val2, val3" will be split in three rows, and the field containing "val1, val2" in two rows. That is why SOF insists on you providing a small reproducible example.